# Any way to tell if a node is in devMode from a flow?

Tags: corda

It doesn’t look like there is any API that can let me check this.

I would like to change behavior of the flow during testing or development. I currently have have a flow that a BNO runs to give permission to a node to do certain things. To make dev easier, I just want to open up all the permissions during development but lock them down in production.

Any one can help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just read the configuration file using https://github.com/lightbend/config , which is what Corda uses internally as well, and see if devMode is set to true.

You can see how Corda parses the config file in https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/c533792f3f7015d07d792a849f4f610f3e23cced/node/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/node/services/config/ConfigUtilities.kt -- and just replicate that

Answer (score 0):

Can you maybe create an abstract flow class and two implementations that diverge only for the permission part you want to change?

(even better would be to make the two implementations diverge only for what concerns the resource you’re accessing - in one case you mock it locally, in the other you access the real resource? Of course I’m not familiar with your setup so this might be wide off the mark)

You might simply be able to write your tests explicitly using the “testing” implementation of the flow and make sure the two implementations diverge as little as possible. Or split off the logic that opens the permission and simply test the rest?